# Play sound from assets folder on iphone simulator Phonegap

Tags: ios, audio, cordova, path

Im trying to play a sound which is located in my asset folder; www/cssScript/sound/Chicken.mp3. Im using the media object from phonegap to do so, and it works fine on Android, and I know its no problem with the media object itself. Im trying to play it in my simulator, but are not able to do so, and have no iPhone currently available.

Is it possible to play audio located locally with the iphone simulator? If so, what do I do wrong? This is the path I give to my media object:

```
     /Users/thomastveten/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/7.0.3/Applications/5F9867C8-1919-4238-87F9-EED4EA893155/GuessThisSound.app/www/cssScript/sound/Chicken.mp3
```

I get the path by using the code below:

```
        var path = window.location.pathname;
    // path = path.substr( 0, path.length - 10 );

    // return path;

    var phoneGapPath = path.substring(0, path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
```